# Call with Retrofit method delete Yii2 which is overrided

Tags: android, rest, yii2, retrofit

I've overrided method delete in my Yii2 controller, but i can not call it from Android application with library Retrofit.

```
public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $model=$this->findModel($id);
        if($model->delete())
        {
            $this->setHeader(200);
            echo json_encode(array('status'=>1,'data'=>array_filter($model->attributes)),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->setHeader(400);
            echo json_encode(array('status'=>0,'error_code'=>400,'errors'=>$model->errors),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        }
    }
```

I tried 2 versions of calling:
first

```
@DELETE("posts/delete/{id}")
```

second

```
 @DELETE("posts/{id}")

Call<Void> deletePosts(@Path("id") int id);
```

But I get error 404. So how should I correctly call this method?

When I try to call not overrided method I get error 500.
Maybe somebody knows how can I call delete method from Android to Yii2 rest?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: **I've overrided method delete in my Yii2 controller** is confusing , do you have a base controller where this action is defined already? and are you able to access this action via postman or a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

To pass a parameter as in `public function actionDelete($id)`, you need to call `/posts/delete?id=<id>`, not just `/posts/delete/<id>`. However, getting this wrong should result in a HTTP 400 Bad Request error, not in a 404 Not Found error.

Possible reason for the 404 error: I assume `$model=$this->findModel($id);` is generated code. If so, it's likely throwing a `NotFoundHttpException` exception if a model with the given ID could not be found.

Another thing you can check is if a [VerbFilter](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-verbfilter) is configured in the `behaviors()` method of your controller to only allow POST requests for the delete action. You might be sending a GET request.